# c# type of panels, want to be free at placing labels

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, dockpanel

I have a form that is getting too big for all functions.
I'd like a 2nd window, or form or panel or whatever to divide the functions.

The simplest way to do so, was create 2 panels and a button that switches between those panels.
Via hide or show. This works fine.

What bothers me, probably of ignorance, is that i can only place a Stackpanel, DockPanel, ToolbarPanel or a Wrappanel. None of those allow me to place labels, or buttons at a F-R-E-E place where i want.
The buttons get alligned at the side, according to which type of panel.

I want a simple panel without the stacking or docking or whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on Windows Forms/WPF/Web? Please add more details.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Put a Grid inside the panel to allow multiple controls.

Comment: Thanks Hans! That solved it.
(i'm working with WPF)